# How to record the path between two nodes in a xml tree?

Tags: c#, xml, recursion, tree, nodes

I want to be able to record the path that needs to be taken to get from a certain node in the xml tree, to another node. Take this graph in place of an XML tree:

```
   A
  / \
 B   C - D
/   / \
E  F   G
```

For example, if I wanted to record the path from D to E the path would be go up to parent C, go up to parent A, go down to child B, go down to child E. So maybe the actual recorded path would be node D -> node C -> node A -> node B -> node E. How could I record a path like this?

Comment: do a google search on the following `C# walking an XML Tree`

Comment: @MethodMan Already looked at most of the posts that show up.

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm?   Code?   XML library recommendation?

Comment: @kjhughes more of a good algorithm that could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to create the path from each node to the root.  Then compare the nodes in both paths starting at the root and find the last match.  That's the common ancestor.  With that you can truncate each path and just concatenate them together.

```
public static string CreatePath(XElement from, XElement to)
{
  var fromToRoot = from.PathToRoot();
  var rootToTo = to.PathToRoot().Reverse();

  var commonAncestor = rootToTo.Zip(fromToRoot.Reverse(), Tuple.Create)
    .TakeWhile(nodes => nodes.Item1 == nodes.Item2)
    .Select(nodes => nodes.Item1)
    .LastOrDefault();

  if (commonAncestor == null) return "Not connected";

  return string.Join(
    "->",
    fromToRoot.TakeWhile(node => node != commonAncestor)
      .Concat(rootToTo.SkipWhile(node => node != commonAncestor))
      .Select(n => n.Name));
}

public static IEnumerable<XElement> PathToRoot(this XElement from)
{
  yield return from;
  var fromParent = from.Parent;
  while (fromParent != null)
  {
    yield return fromParent;
    fromParent = fromParent.Parent;
  }
}
```